# Is name and description in composer project required or not?

Tags: php, validation, composer-php

I have created a project (not a library) with composer. My composer.json file does not contain a name and a description since I don't want to publish it. According to the docs that should be alright ([doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#name)).

But when I do a `composer.phar validate` or `composer.phar validate --no-check-all` it tells me that both properties are required. Is this a wrong behaviour? Or did I get anything wrong?

Comment: Not sure about this, but even you don't want to publish you project, why won't you set a name and a little description? This should matter for you either

Comment: Of course, it's not a big deal to add it. I was just wondering if I've got anything wrong with projects and libraries.

Comment: maybe this is the same problem as you have: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3606

Comment: It seems so, though I have the latest version (2015-03-04).